# imap returing "blank" unseen message, from an inbox containing no messages

Tags: python, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

So I have successfully put together a lovely program that counts the total unread messages from inside a category within a Gmail account, and posts the data in realtime into a tkinter text box - all seems to work, apart from one really annoying aspect...

The only issue I am having is that the code seems to be counting blank inside Gmail where there are actually 0 messages, trash included.

I want the readout to be 0 submission[s], instead of  submission[s]. How can I get the code below to see no messages as 0?

When 1 unread message is in there however it tells me that 1 message is in there, when there are 2, it says 2. But when there are 0 it returns a blank space followed by the else statement as if it were counting at least one message in the inbox. Frustrating right?

Here is the code that I am using to delve into the Gmail account and count the 'unreads' - ***hopefully I have just done something stupid***...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.4
import imaplib
import email
import tkinter as tk

mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
mail.login('mygmail@gmail.com','mypassword')
mail.select("myinboxlabel")
typ, messageIDs = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN")
memberships = str(messageIDs[0], encoding='utf8')

if memberships == 0:
    info2['text'] = 'no memberships'
else:
    info2['text'] = '{} membership[s]'.format(memberships)
```

Comment: Looks like memberships is a string variable, and it can never equal to integer 0. So it always goes to else branch. You might want to try "not memberships.strip()" instead of "memberships == 0".

Comment: Hey Chun-Yen, thank you for taking a look. Please pardon my absolute ignorance but how would that actually look inside the code? This is the first program I have ever undertaken. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. could you replace "if memberships == 0:" with "if (not memberships) or (not memberships.strip()):"

Comment: Nice, that worked like a charm! Thank you.